# Was trying to fix wireless now UBUNTU COMPLETELY OFFLINE no wired connectivity. What to do?

Tags: internet

This is basically the worst case. Rebooted to move and was trying to get wifi working again. dkms etc. Maybe uninstall network manager. Not sure what caused this but am completely offline now.

How can I restore wired connectivity?

Comment: Do you remember how you got network manager removed?

Comment: Yes, I removed it with apt-get trying to rejib thing. All sorted now. Good to remember that snap appears to have a cache for times like this.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

snap install network-manager

/etc/init.d/network-manager restart

This is scary stuff. Should not be possible to get into this state so easily.